# Warning error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null php 7.4

Tags: php

Hola buenos días estoy teniendo problemas con la version 7.4 en esta consulta que realizo

```
$consult = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM status WHERE id = '$oldstatus' ");
$register = $consult->fetch_assoc();
$oldstatus = $register['name'];
```

Comment: Esa consulta no te devuelve ningún valor, debes verificar si tienes datos antes de asignar a `$oldstatus`.

Answer (score 4):

Buen día, para evitar este tipo de error, tiene que agregar una condición de isset para validar que exista la variable.

```
$consult = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM status WHERE id = '$oldstatus' ");
$register = $consult->fetch_assoc();
if(isset($register['name'])){
    $oldstatus = $register['name'];
}
```